# Is "look at him in that..." natural?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> Guy 1: "Where is Mike?"
>
> Guy 2: "There he is! Hahaha! **Look at him in that ugly shirt!**"

Would the emboldened part be natural in the context for a native speaker? (With 'him' referring to Mike.)

Comment: Perfectly normal. Did you think it was not?

Comment: Wasn't sure if "look at" was natural? Would "see him in that ugly shirt" also be natural?

Comment: Yes. The idea is to draw attention to the ugly shirt.

Comment: @user141956 "See him in that ugly shirt" is only natural if it's a question meaning "(Do you) see him in that ugly shirt?"